# Should delete operations take into account optimistic locking?

Tags: rest, optimistic-locking

In a REST API, the agent sends a DELETE request to /some-resource/666

Should that be enough? Or should they send the resource ID as well as the version (used for optimistic locking), so that they can ensure they are deleting the version that they read?

Answer (score 2):

This heavily depends on the context.

- If your resource `id` is server-generated and always unique (for example, it could be that `POST /some-resource` returns a new `id` that is a GUID for the resource or is a SQL autoincrement column), then you certainly don't need to specify any specific `version` to delete and `DELETE /some-resource/{id}` is sufficient.
- If your resource `id` is client-generated or only unique among currently existing resources (repeatable), then you could add a `version` query parameter as you are suggesting.

  - A question you have to ask though is: if you have non-unique or repeatable `id` values, can you easily make them instead always unique? If so, prefer that solution to the `version` parameter on `DELETE`.

Comment: In the first case, I would say that specifying a version is also useful to make sure that the record that the user wants to delete is still in the same state as the user last saw it. If that's not the case (i.e. it changed in the meantime, probably by someone else), then maybe the user does not want to delete it any more!

Comment: Maybe the right answer is to use both a non repeatable ID (to ensure the user deletes the right object - the object may have been deleted and created again by a concurrent user) and a version field (to ensure the user deletes the object when it has the same state as the last time it fetched it).